# Binding gridview from sql table but this binding not for particular table it keeps on changing depending on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called `TableExplorer` which contains other table's names and their respective column names.

For example: table `Customer` may have 5 columns but in `TableExplorer` I may mention only 2 column names out of 5.

User send me the table name in query string, my job is to find that table name whether it is present or not in `TableExplorer` which I mentioned initially. If the user mentioned table is present then I should bind that table to a gridview and that gridview should have functionality like edit, delete, update. Finally any operation like edit, delete or update made by user should reflect in the respective table as mentioned by the user.

- Database used : SQL Server 2008 R2
- Programming language : C#, ASP.NET

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: how many tables do you want to be able to load and bind?

Comment: Thanks Vland for the suggestion. But I have more than 92 tables in my requirement. So is there any way to achieve my requirement by making everything generic I mean Only one webpage, one gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `WebForms`? I'm far from being a WebForms expert but this is what I'd do:

You create different pages with `GridView` control, one for each table that you might want to bind, eg. `Customer` table. You create the CRUD operation for this GridView, Insert, Update, Delete. You create parameters for all the columns that the user might need, some of them could be invisible.

The user goes to his selection page, he choses a table and a list of columns and press Submit his request. Whenever you receive the  query string you do 2 things:

1. Identify what table your user is asking and load the right page, if available. Maybe you can load only the specific GridView control in a specific  using Ajax. Or maybe you can simple load another page.
2. Get the list of columns that the user wants to see in his grid from the querystring. Before showing the grid to him you keep these columns visible and hide/remove from the gridview every other column. You must pass this parameter to your insert/update methods as well.

I think this is a good solution to start, assuming you don't have a list of hundreds of tables, I wouldn't try to create something *completely dynamic*.